# wait function in if condition statement

Tags: c, unix, wait

In the following code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main (void) {
   pid_t childpid;
   childpid = fork();
   if (childpid == -1) {
   /* set up signal handlers here ... */
      perror("Failed to fork");
      return 1;
   }
   if (childpid == 0)
      fprintf(stderr, "I am child %ld\n", (long)getpid());
   else if (wait(NULL) != childpid)
      fprintf(stderr, "A signal must have interrupted the wait!\n");
   else
      fprintf(stderr, "I am parent %ld with child %ld\n", (long)getpid(),
           (long)childpid);
   return 0;
}
```

How will the multiple if else statement behave? If child process does not return immediately, will the condition inside the else if statement always be false and then execute the else statement?

Comment: The computer will evaluate `wait(NULL) != childpid` before it can know whether to execute the 2nd or 3rd `fprintf`. That won't finish until `wait` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If child process does not return immediately, will the condition inside the else if statement always be false and then execute the else statement?

The call to `wait` is a blocking call. It will block until the state of the child has changed or it is interrupted by a signal.

From  http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait

> A state change is considered to be: the child terminated; the child was stopped by a signal; or the child was resumed by a signal.

and

> Otherwise they block until either a child changes state or a signal handler interrupts the call